# Cannot find "RasterCalc" plugin from the QGIS Official Plugin Reposity (2.18)

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, raster-calculator

I have recently installed QGIS 2.18 (Las Palmas) and would like to run the RasterCalc plugin for raster processing.

The home page for the plugin:

```
http://gis-lab.info/qa/rastercalc-eng.html
```

The official QGIS Plugin Repository is:

```
https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/plugins.xml?qgis=2.18
```

I tried to search for the key word "RasterCalc" or "raster calc" but nothing was returned.

Is this plugin no longer supported in the official plugin repository or did I do anything wrong?

Answer (score 1):

RasterCalc has not been a separate plugin for a very long time (years and many versions).  It is part of the core QGIS GUI as [Raster Calculator](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_calculator.html).  Simply go to `Raster->Raster Calculator` (no extra plugin required).